# What is the reason for the boiling point of benzene-1,4-diol being higher than that of benzene-1,3-diol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, boiling-point, hydrogen-bond

What is the reason for the boiling point of benzene-1,4-diol being higher than that of benzene-1,3-diol?

[image: Resorcinol]


[image: Quinol]

Both have hydrogen bonds. I think it is due to quinol's symmetry but can't point out exactly why this is the case.

Comment: Can you take a guess? Have you not been provided with other examples? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112078/what-effect-on-boiling-and-melting-points-does-intramolecular-hydrogen-bonding-h

Comment: @Lllt: Not related question. None of these two can make intramolecular hydrogen bonding.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne I think benzene 1,3 diol can do so

Comment: symmetry makes it have a lot less dipole moment than resorcinol. I think this has to do with larger surface area of quinol leading to higher Vander Waal forces.

Comment: @napstablook By symmetry, I meant its packing and all in liquid state

Comment: @RobinSingh packing in liquid state?

Comment: @napstablook I'm sorry I don't have a way with words. I mean the ease with which they can form h bonds

Answer (score 1):

[Benzene-1,4-diol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroquinone)  has a boiling point of 287°C and [Benzene-1,3-diol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resorcinol) has a boiling point of 277°C and [Benzene-1,2-diol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catechol) has a boiling point of 245.5°C. This could be attributed to the ease of formation of 2 intermolecular hydrogen bonds with the 2 hydroxy groups of these molecules increasing when the hydroxy groups are placed apart, to minimise steric hindrance and repulsion. Benzene-1,4-diol could form intermolecular hydrogen bonds with more stability than Benzene-1,3-diol or Benzene-1,2-diol as these two will get destabilised by steric repulsion when large groups have to reach nearer to form hydrogen bonds.

Thus, the extent of intermolecular hydrogen bonding in :
Benzene-1,4-diol > Benzene-1,3-diol > Benzene-1,2-diol

To overcome this attraction, more energy is needed. Hence the same is the order of their Boiling Points.

Comment: Is that good enough of a reason for a 10°C rise?